# Java - Threads runned with Executors.newFixedThreadPool are never finished

Tags: java, multithreading

I have threads those should be finished, but did not do that. There is a stacktrace in each thread (checked with debugger):

```
Unsafe.park(boolean, long) line: not available [native method]  
LockSupport.park(Object) line: not available    
AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() line: not available  
LinkedBlockingQueue<E>.take() line: not available   
ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() line: not available    
ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: not available 
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: not available 
Thread.run() line: not available
```

The code:

```
ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
int totalNumberOfTasks = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(expr != null) {
        totalNumberOfTasks++;
        threadExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doSmth();
            }
        });
    }
}
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(totalNumberOfTasks);
try {
    latch.await();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I also tried to use `Semaphor` instead of `CountDownLatch`, but had the same result. Can someone help me please?

Comment: You are not counting down the latch ... so you wait forever. Totally expected result.

Comment: Yes, I see. But probably `CountDownLatch` is not useful in my case, when the number of tasks is not predefined. How `Semaphore` should be used inside a `Runnable`?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

// Must be available in Runnables
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(size);

int totalNumberOfTasks = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(expr != null) {
        totalNumberOfTasks++;
        threadExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doSmth();
                latch.countDown(); // Countdown the latch
            }
        });
    }
}

try {
    latch.await();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you do not know the number of tasks beforehand, you could use [`invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)):

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to count down the latch when a worker thread finishes.
I wouldn't use the `CountDownLatch` at all but rely on the `ExecutorService`'s `shutdown` and `awaitTermination` methods to wait for the threads to finish:

```
ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(expr != null) {
        threadExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doSmth();
            }
        });
    }
}

threadExecutor.shutdown();
try {
    threadExecutor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    // handle timeout
}
```